# Relação entre dados com combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, estou com uma aplicação em C# utilizando Windows Forms

Minha dúvida seria a seguinte.
Estou com um banco de dados feito no Access
Nele contem 2 tabelas, uma tabela chamada Estado, que contém Código e Estado e outra tabela chamada Cidades, que contém Código, Estado e Cidade.

Lembrando que tenho 2 combobox, o primeiro combobox é preenchido com os dados da tabela Estado, utilizando bindingsource, até ai está tudo certo, ele aparece todos os códigos de estado.
A dúvida que tenho seria a seguinte, eu queria fazer um relacionamento entre a combobox 1 e a 2, sendo que a 2 irá mostrar todos as cidades, de acordo com o estado selecionado, porém no bindingsource, não tem uma opção de filtragem, e estou com dúvida para como colocar isso.

Usando uma pesquisa no banco sairá desse método:

```
SELECT Cidade FROM Cidades WHERE Estado='" + sel_UF + "'
```

li alguns tópicos também na internet e alguns aqui mesmo no stackoverflow, porém não consegui sanar minha dúvida, em que fala para colocar algo relacionado dentro do evento:

```
SelectedValueChanged
```

Se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz ai, desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha se isto te ajuda!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace CidadesEstados
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DB.accdb");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carregarComboboxEstados();
            cb_estado.Text = "";
        }

        public void carregarComboboxEstados()
        {


          try
            {

                if (!(cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                }
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT cod,estado FROM Estado", cnn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                cb_estado.DataSource = dt;
                cb_estado.ValueMember = "estado";
                cb_estado.DisplayMember = "estado";
                cnn.Close();

            }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message , "Erro");
            }
        }

        public void carregarComboboxCidades()
        {

            try
            {

                if (!(cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                }
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT cod,estado,cidade FROM Cidade WHERE estado='" + cb_estado.SelectedValue + "'", cnn);
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               da.Fill(dt);
               cb_cidade.DataSource = dt;
               cb_cidade.ValueMember = "estado";
               cb_cidade.DisplayMember = "cidade";
               cnn.Close();

              }
             catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message , "Erro");
            }

        }

        private void cb_estado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carregarComboboxCidades();
        }


    }
}
```

Se desejar baixar o projeto este é o link:
[Cidades e Estados](http://www.mediafire.com/download/nnnjlc5c4xbwp5y/CidadesEstados.rar)

Obrigado!!

Comment: Ajuda sim, consegui por outro metodo, criei um metodo pra buscar no FillBy, pesquisando apenas a parte do estado e cidade, mas este também fica muito bom

Answer (score 1):

Simples

Chamaremos o COMBO ESTADO e COMBO CIDADO.

Você irá preencher o combo estado como está fazendo agora sem problemas, porém irá adicionar um evento no COMBO ESTADO, o `SelectedIndexChanged`

neste evento, você vai carregar os dados do combo estado.

```
protected virtual void SelectedIndexChanged (EventArgs e){

DDLCidade.DataSrouce = "AQUI VOCÊ MANDA SUA LISTA DE CIDADES FILTRADA";
DDLCidade.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Ainda fiquei sem entender, sem contar que seu exemplo é em asp.net, preciso de algo em c# mesmo, para windows form application, e o jeito que esta talvez não funcionasse, pois no banco tem todas as cidades e estado ja, só basta ele saber selecionar qual ele quer

Comment: Qual parte você não entendeu?

Comment: o conceito pode ate ser parecido, mas na declaração do código é diferente de asp para c#

Comment: Basta usar o evento correto que dá certo.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cadastro_funcionario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(herança.caminho);//herança.caminho é o caminho ca minha base de dados 
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from empresa";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds,"empresa");
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["empresa"];
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "nome";
        conn.Close();
        comboBox1.Enabled = true;
    } catch (Exception erro) {
        MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria bom se você explicasse melhor sua resposta...